# Text Extraction from natural images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a problem while executing this code. I want to extract text from images this is my code

```
i = imread('handicapped.jpg');
i1 = rgb2gray(i);
imshow(i1);

i2 = edge(i1,'canny',0.3);
imshow(i2);

se = strel('square',2);
i3 = imdilate(i2,se);
imshow(i3);

i4 = imfill(i3,'holes');
imshow(i4);

[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(i4);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 92]);
imshow(i);

hold on;
for cnt = 1:92
rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
end
```

I have an error in line 19

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in test11 (line 19)
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 92]);
```

can anyone help me???

Comment: Start by understanding the error. Why is reshape used and why with those dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the assumption that there are *always* 92 bounding boxes found. You are getting an error because this obviously isn't always the case. Instead of specifying the second dimension to `reshape`, [you can pass an empty array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html#inputarg_sz1szN) so that `reshape` will figure out the appropriate dimensions.

```
%// 4 Rows with numel(Ibox)/4 columns
Ibox = reshape(Ibox, 4, []);
```

Your for loop makes the same assumption of 92 so you will need to change that as well

```
for cnt = 1:size(Ibox, 2)
    rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much i am following this approach for text detection from images but its not working well please help me to suggest any good approach, i am waiting for your reply :)

Comment: Because i want to use any advance technique that help me in my thesis. i am doing MS. But if you suggest ocr good for this than i will go with ocr.

Comment: @NomanMalik You can use whatever you would like. There are many ways to do text recognition, but `ocr` is the built-in way within MATLAB to do it.

Comment: Please tell me about these techniques?